# Is i-doser legal in Singapore?

Tags: singapore

Drug is illegal in Singapore. i-doser claims to be a musical drug. Namely it's music whose effect similar to drugs. Indonesian government say it's not a drug. It's just a marketing gimmick.

Will it be legal?

http://i-doser.com/

Will I get death penalty if I bring i-doser there?

Plan to share that with a girl. Perhaps jokingly says (to the girl) I bring some drug.

Anyway, what I want to ask is if there is any law or convictions in Singapore where people in jail because of i-doser

Comment: Why would you walk music through customs?  Rip it, throw it away, push it to the cloud and download it once you're home. Who buys music on physical media anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get the death penalty because it is not really a drug.

But, if you joke around with customs, you will no doubt find yourself in jail for a few days and experience unpleasant cavity searches.

Never joke around with customs. A lack of a sense of humor is one of their hiring criteria.

Comment: the i-doser app is in my cellphone

Comment: I do not think I will tell anything to custom. What I want to ask is if there is any law in Singapore that prohibits i-doser.com. If it's illegal in anyway I won't bring it.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t bring drugs to Singapore. Don’t bring anything to Singapore that might be thought of as drugs. Jails in Singapore are no fun.

If you ask “will I get the death penalty if I do X”” then the correct answer is “ don’t do it”.